# Connection to node terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kerberos

Our producers are kubernetes microservices which use Kerberos authentication to connect to Kafka.What we see if when there is a rolling restart of Kafka brokers we see the below errors in our producer and consumer end:

kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-4] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - processDisconnection - [Producer clientId=producer-4] Connection to node 5 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.

Any idea why the producer/consumer retries do not automatically connect without any issues. The way we are able to resolve this issue is by pod restarts.

Comment: The clients will reconnect. Your Kerberos ticket seems to be expiring, which is a separate issue that restarting will fix

Comment: onecricketeer thanks for getting back. Can you please suggest how to keep the Kerberos ticket from expiring

Comment: I don't use Kerberos with Kafka. I was just pointing out your error is due to auth failure, not a network exception